# Dropdownlist not showing previous value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net dropdownlist control with autopostback false.
I have written js code to display confirm message while dropdown value changed.

```
function ConfirmAbsent(ddlPresence) {
        if (ddlPresence != null) {
            var myValue = ddlPresence.options[ddlPresence.selectedIndex].text;
            var blnAbsent = confirm("This will mark as "+ myValue +". Please confirm clicking OK.");

            if (blnAbsent) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And add this attribute to dropdownlist like below

```
ddlUserPresence.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if (!ConfirmAbsent(" + ddlUserPresence.ClientID
                    + ")) return; else __doPostBack('"
                    + ddlUserPresence.UniqueID + "', '');");
```

When i click on ok button it postback the page working correctly, but when i click on cancel button it is not showing me the previous value instead showing the current value.

So when i click on cancel button it should show me the previous value.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should `return false` from the event handler if you want to prevent the event:

```
ddlUserPresence.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return(ConfirmAbsent(" + ddlUserPresence.ClientID +"));");
```

You are also passing the ClientID of the `DropDownList` but you're not using it to find the control. So you should use `document.GetElementById`.

```
function ConfirmAbsent(ddlPresenceID) {
    var ddlPresence = document.GetElementById(ddlPresenceID);
    if (ddlPresence != null) {
```

Note that you can use [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) to get the initial value that was set on serverside for TextBoxes.

Comment: @akeeseth: `AutoPostback` is not an event. The dropdown will only postback immediately with `AutoPostback="true"` and when the clientside handler returns true. So if you return `false` from `onchange`, the dropdown will not postback.

Comment: Once the onchange fires, it is too late to prevent the selection. You have to remember the select before the onchange and set it back. If you use onclick or onfocus you can pick up the current index so when the onchange fires you will have the previous selection.